# How to make primitive type properties Optional?

Tags: jsonmodel

I want to make some primitive properties option in my JSONModel classes. Please see the code below.

```
#import "JSONModel.h"

@protocol GreenModel <NSObject>
@end

@interface MyModel : JSONModel

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger<Optional> objId;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@end
```

Can anybody suggest a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can do this by using propertyIsOptional:. Just return YES for the names of the properties you want to make Optional.

https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel#make-all-model-properties-optional-avoid-if-possible

```
+(BOOL)propertyIsOptional:(NSString*)propertyName
{
  if ([propertyName isEqualToString: @"objId"]) return YES;
  return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For swift

Please use following code in the sub class of your JSON model. If you want to give all the properties as optional then the code will looks like this:

```
override class func propertyIsOptional(propertyName: String!) -> Bool    {
   return true
}
```

If you want a specific property the code will looks like this:

```
override class func propertyIsOptional(propertyName: String!) -> Bool     {
if propertyName == "your_property_name"
{
    return true
}
    return false
}
```

Comment: Please use code formatting tool and edit your answer