# About JSONModel, how can i make primitive type property Optional?

Tags: ios, jsonmodel

I am using JSONModle, but i meet a problem, i am not sure how can i handle it?

```
@interface MessageModel : JSONModel

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString*           create_at;
@property(nonatomic, assign) long                message_id;
@property(nonatomic, assign) int                 message_type;    
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString<Optional>* text;
@property(nonatomic, assign) int<Optional>       background_no;   
@end
```

About property `background_no`, it's type is `int`, can i use `Optional`? If not, how can i do?

Comment: This questions has been asked literally hundreds of times on public repos and so, just use the delegate method propertyIsOptional:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only apply protocols to Objective-C objects, not to primitive types.  You will therefore need to use `NSNumber` to store the `int`:

```
@property(nonatomic) NSNumber<Optional> *background_no;
```

and use auto-boxing, to store it:

```
someObject.background_no = @(123);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21778271/how-to-make-primitive-type-properties-optional what's about this method?

Comment: @BlackMamba That isn't really the question you asked.  That other method may work, I've no idea.  I would suggest searching for and trying other solutions *before* asking questions.

Comment: @BlackMamba: Yes, the **propertyIsOptional** method works just fine, I'm using it in my iOS App for several primitive properties. For objects I'm still applying the **Optional** protocol.